# Setting vendor-prefixed CSS using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, vendor-prefix

...is a huge pain.

```
var transform = 'translate3d(0,0,0)';
elem.style.webkitTransform = transform;
elem.style.mozTransform = transform;
elem.style.msTransform = transform;
elem.style.oTransform = transform;
```

Is there a library/framework/better way to do this? Preferably with just one line of JS?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't know of any library that does this, but if they are all just *prefixes*--that is, there is no difference in name or syntax--writing a function yourself would be trivial.

```
function setVendor(element, property, value) {
  element.style["webkit" + property] = value;
  element.style["moz" + property] = value;
  element.style["ms" + property] = value;
  element.style["o" + property] = value;
}
```

Then you can just use this in most cases.

Comment: Make sure you capitalize the property name (`Transform` instead of `transform`). I discovered this the hard way...

Comment: [Regarding capitalization of vendor-prefixed CSS property names in JavaScript](https://alanhogan.com/code/vendor-prefixed-css-property-names-in-javascript): tl;dr Do capitalize them, although in practice it doesn’t matter with Webkit!

Comment: I must say that this answer really is just slightly better than in the question :D

Answer (score 17):

It's currently late 2015, and the situation has changed slightly. First of all, McBrainy's comment about capitalization above is important. The `webkit` prefix is now `Webkit`, but luckily only used by Safari at this point. Both Chrome and Firefox support `el.style.transform` without the prefix now, and I think IE does as well. Below is a slightly more modern solution for the task at hand. It first checks to see if we even need to prefix our transform property:

```
var transformProp = (function(){
  var testEl = document.createElement('div');
  if(testEl.style.transform == null) {
    var vendors = ['Webkit', 'Moz', 'ms'];
    for(var vendor in vendors) {
      if(testEl.style[ vendors[vendor] + 'Transform' ] !== undefined) {
        return vendors[vendor] + 'Transform';
      }
    }
  }
  return 'transform';
})();
```

Afterwards, we can just use a simple one-liner call to update the `transform` property on an element:

```
myElement.style[transformProp] = 'translate3d(0,' + dynamicY + 'px,0)';
```

Comment: Seems that Firefox support for non-prefixed transforms is pretty widespread now: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 7):

You can find the respective vendor prefix using Javascript with the following code-

```
var prefix = (function () {
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, ''),
    pre = (Array.prototype.slice
      .call(styles)
      .join('') 
      .match(/-(moz|webkit|ms)-/) || (styles.OLink === '' && ['', 'o'])
    )[1],
    dom = ('WebKit|Moz|MS|O').match(new RegExp('(' + pre + ')', 'i'))[1];
  return {
    dom: dom,
    lowercase: pre,
    css: '-' + pre + '-',
    js: pre[0].toUpperCase() + pre.substr(1)
  };
})();
```

The above returns an object of the respective browser's vendor prefix.

Saved a lot of duplicate code in my scripts.

Source - David Walsh's blog: https://davidwalsh.name/vendor-prefix

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your externally linked answer directly here, as an external source might change.

Comment: This method plays off of the fact that there will always be a vendor-prefixed property in the style declaration.

Answer (score 3):

There's this jquery plugin that take care of it
https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Css3-Finalize

Comment: He did not ask for a jquery tool.

Comment: @AdamArold He asked for 'a library/framework/better way to do this'. This can be a jQuery plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up your workflow with Gulp for example you can use Postcss [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) which is handy tool in solving browser vendor prefixes. It uses JS to transform you css.