# changing css background style with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I'm trying to change the css `background` style in JavaScript. I'm able to do this

`div.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/bg1.png')";`

but when I try to add these styles it doesn't work - it returns with this error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - (index):59`

```
div.style.-webkit-background-size = cover;
div.style.-moz-background-size = cover;
div.style.-o-background-size = cover;
div.style.background-size = cover;
```

is it possible to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8889149/4453045

Comment: You cannot set the vendor specific CSS styles that way. In fact, you don't even need to set them.