# JasvaScript: Does JavaScript Have The Cross-Browser Capabilities As CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I noticed how CSS has Cross-Browser arguments such as `-webkit-`, and `-moz-` as well as `Media Queries`. Does JavaScript Have an equivalent using `element.style.["Cross-Browser];` or any other method? I usually use JavaScript to define all of my elements and I am considering switching to HTML and CSS. Here is an example for this problem is:

**CSS**

```
#div{
    -webkit-padding:4px;
    -moz-padding:4px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener("load", Start);
function Start(){
    var Div = getElementById("div");
    Div.style.padding = "4px"; //Universal [Works!]
    Div.style.moz.padding = "4px"; //Firefox [Doesn't Work! Why?]
    Div.style.mozPadding = "4px"; //Firefox [Doesn't Work! Why?]
    Div.style.webkit.padding = "4px"; //Chrome or Opera [Doesn't Work! Why?]
    Div.style.webkitPadding = "4px"; //Chrome or Opera [Doesn't Work! Why?]
    document.body.appendChild(Div);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889014/setting-vendor-prefixed-css-using-javascript

Comment: Why don't you just try it out and see if it works?

Comment: @Connum I'm pretty sure they don't work. I want someone to confirm it.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko - and you can't because?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can and I did, they don't but why? Does JavaScript keep up with CSS or am I missing something?

Comment: @adeneo the solution the posted doesn't work. I keep getting `ReferenceError: Padding is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use the same string as with css, but with the following syntax because of the dashes.

```
Div.style["-webkit-padding"] = "4px";
```

Comment: I tried this and It's not working.