# Is this already code browser supported?

Tags: javascript, css

Is this code automatically browser supported?:

```
document.getElementById('test').style.animation = 'FadeOut 1s';
```

Or do i have to add extensions to it for other browsers' support like for example:
-webkit-
-moz-
-o-

If so how would its syntax be?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation - TL;DR: Yes, it's supported in all major browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889014/setting-vendor-prefixed-css-using-javascript

Comment: [does not work](http://jsbin.com/ripazisaza/edit?output) (chrome mobile)